# Expected minimum absolute value of unifrom distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider we draw N iid values $x_1, x_2,...,x_N$ from an uniform distribution on $[- \epsilon, \epsilon]$. Can we calculate the expected minimum of their absolute values:
$$
\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{min}(|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_n|))
$$

If yes, can we even generalize this in higher diemensions, that is $x_1, x_2,...,x_N \in \mathbb{R}^K$ and $|\cdot|$ beeing any norm that works.

Comment: The univariate case is quite straightforward. Since $X_i$ follows a uniform distribution which is symmetric about $0$uniform distribution, $|X_i| \sim \text{Uniform}(0, \epsilon)$. By re-scaling it, the expectation is equivalent to $\epsilon E[\min\{Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_n\}]$ where $Z_i$ are standard uniform. It is well known that the minimum of standard uniform follows $\text{Beta}(1, n)$ with expectation $1/(n+1)$. Therefore the result is $\epsilon/(n + 1)$

Comment: Thank you, that helped already, do you also have an approach for the high dimensional case though?

Comment: The calculation will depends on the norm you chosen and the generalization. Assume you mean that the generalization is to generalize those $X_i$ in a $k$-dimensional hypercube such that each dimension is i.i.d. as the univariate case (if you generalize to a $k$-ball, that will be different). For simplicity, we assume $\epsilon = 1$ first. The maximum norm will follow $\text{Beta(k,1)}$, i.e. CDF is $u^k$. Then the survival function of $\min \|X_i\|$ is $(1-u^k)^n$ and thus the expectation is $\int_0^1(1-u^k)^ndu=\int_0^1\frac{1}{k}t^{1/k-1}(1-t)^ndt=\frac{1}{k}\text{Beta}(\frac{1}{k},n+1)$

Comment: Do you know some resources where this is calculated in more detail, I would be interested to read it. And also, is all of this still possible if we consider |x_1 - c|, |x_2 - c|,... with c in the hypercube?

Comment: I do not have resource specific on this topic as what you see I have only do some elementary calculations. Every generalization is possible theoretically, but the calculations may become too tedious to handle / no closed-form solution.